# Can't implement Android ImageAnalysis.Analyzer interface with void analyze(ImageProxy)

Tags: java, android, google-mlkit

I tried to create a `QrAnalyzer` class that implements the `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer` interface like in [the barcode scanning tutorial](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android#java) like so:

```java
class QrAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    @Override
    public void analyze(ImageProxy imageProxy) {
        Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
        if (mediaImage != null) {
            InputImage image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
        }
    }
}
```

but I got the following error:

> Class 'QrAnalyzer' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'analyze(ImageProxy, int)' in 'Analyzer'

It appears that the interface declares `analyze` to have 2 parameters: an `ImageProxy` and an `int`.
However, according to [ImageAnalysis.Analyzer documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.Analyzer) this is not true. What is that 2nd `int`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using an old (alpha/beta?) version of the classes/libraries in question.

Compare: https://androidx.tech/artifacts/camera/camera-core/1.0.0-alpha06-source/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.java.html

This is an alpha version which has the interface implemented using method - `void analyze(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees);`

To https://androidx.tech/artifacts/camera/camera-core/1.0.0-rc01-source/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.java.html

This release candidate version has the interface requiring method `void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image);`

In either case the parameter in question is the rotation in degrees of the image, which you are getting instead via `imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees()` .